# Cannot create a new project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, vs-community-edition

Here's a very weird issue I'm having, it was fine a few days ago:

[image]

Any way to fix that?

Basically a template chooser opens after I press OK and nothing else happens.

Comment: Does it still happen after a reinstall? Have you tried deleting the install directory after uninstalling?

Comment: @EricS Didn't reinstalled, thought it might take a quick fix to solve.

Comment: Another idea, and just guessing here. Have you tried to reset your default VS settings? It may save a reinstall.

Comment: @EricS I believe I haven't touched them since install. I opened up installation menu now and selected repair.

Comment: @EricS Recently I installed Office 365, if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Today I experienced the same problem (on Windows 10, VS 2015 Enterprise with 3 updates), even though the initial installation *had* the full C++ package selected. The fix which worked for me was quite time-consuming (and the suggestions I found online did not help too much). Here's what worked for me:

1. Navigate to the IDE folder, usually located at C:\Program Files \Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE;
2. From IDE delete two folders: **ItemTemplatesCache**, **ProjectTemplatesCache**;
3. Open VS 2015 Command Line Tools as administrator. Run the following: **devenv /InstallVSTemplates**. Then run: **devenv /Setup**;
4. Make sure Windows 10 updates were installed correctly by running the Update Troubleshooter (in my case it found and fixed a couple of errors);
5. Repair VS2015 using the installer;
6. Once the repair is done, uninstall the redistributables for VS2015 C++;
7. Install the [redistributables from MSDN](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52685).

That worked for me. I did have to restart quite often, and used CCleaner to clean up registries after the uninstall process. Depending on your situation, not all the steps may be applicable. I do hope this fix works for you too!